# How do you reshape a csv file in python using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to reshape this csv file in python to have 1,000 rows and all 12 columns but it shows up as only one column

I've tried using df.iloc[:][:1000] it shortens it to 1000 rows but it still only gives me 1 column

## Dataframe for Wine

```
df_w= pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv') 
df_w= df_w.iloc[:12][:1000]
df_w
```

The dataframe that shows up is 1000 rows with only 1 column and I'm wondering how you set the data into its respective column title

Answer (score 0):

Use `sep=';'`, for semicolon delimiter:

```
df_w= pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv', sep=';')
df_w= df_w.iloc[:12][:1000]
df_w
```

Output:

```
    fixed acidity  volatile acidity  citric acid  residual sugar  chlorides  free sulfur dioxide  total sulfur dioxide  density    pH  sulphates  alcohol  quality
0             7.4              0.70         0.00             1.9      0.076                 11.0                  34.0   0.9978  3.51       0.56      9.4        5
1             7.8              0.88         0.00             2.6      0.098                 25.0                  67.0   0.9968  3.20       0.68      9.8        5
2             7.8              0.76         0.04             2.3      0.092                 15.0                  54.0   0.9970  3.26       0.65      9.8        5
3            11.2              0.28         0.56             1.9      0.075                 17.0                  60.0   0.9980  3.16       0.58      9.8        6
4             7.4              0.70         0.00             1.9      0.076                 11.0                  34.0   0.9978  3.51       0.56      9.4        5
5             7.4              0.66         0.00             1.8      0.075                 13.0                  40.0   0.9978  3.51       0.56      9.4        5
6             7.9              0.60         0.06             1.6      0.069                 15.0                  59.0   0.9964  3.30       0.46      9.4        5
7             7.3              0.65         0.00             1.2      0.065                 15.0                  21.0   0.9946  3.39       0.47     10.0        7
8             7.8              0.58         0.02             2.0      0.073                  9.0                  18.0   0.9968  3.36       0.57      9.5        7
9             7.5              0.50         0.36             6.1      0.071                 17.0                 102.0   0.9978  3.35       0.80     10.5        5
10            6.7              0.58         0.08             1.8      0.097                 15.0                  65.0   0.9959  3.28       0.54      9.2        5
11            7.5              0.50         0.36             6.1      0.071                 17.0                 102.0   0.9978  3.35       0.80     10.5        5
```

Comment: @PrivateJD2 did this solution help you?  Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)?